# How do I check a variable in Firebase database?

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

In my app I have a UISearchBar that returns results from the Google Places API. When I tap on a result I'm passing the `place.id` (given a new variable name of `placeId`) to a second view controller where I want to run a check.

For this app I've manually assigned an A/B value to several places in a Firebase database and I want to be able to check if the search result I tap on has value "A" or value "B" based on its `place.id`

Here's my code:

```
    let productRef = rootRef.child("id")
    productRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if(snapshot.exists()){

            let placeId = snapshot.value as? String

            if(self.IDLabel == placeId){
                print("A")
                }
        }
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Am I on the right track? Where do I go from here in order to check if the `place.id` of the result I tap has a value of "A" or "B" in Firebase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I was referencing the wrong variable in my if statement. `self.placeId` was an empty variable elsewhere in the view controller. When I changed it to `IDLabel` (the correct variable I wanted to check) it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

you are storing data as a "key, value" pair but retrieving only the key. it is better to use the equalto() function by setting a Query class. Details in the Firebase documentation here -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data